# Структура БД для хранения непрочитанных сообщений пользователей

Tags: mysql, база-данных

В БД есть таблица *<сообщения_администрации>* в которой будут храниться различные уведомления администрации (нововведения на сайте, новые услуги и т.п.) и есть таблица *<пользователи>*, тут всё понятно

Список сообщений будет один для всех пользователей, т.е. при добавлении нового сообщения в таблицу *<сообщения_администрации>*, его видят все пользователи

Вопрос: как лучше хранить список прочитанных (или не прочитанных) сообщения для каждого пользователя?

Есть идея создать промежуточную таблицу с 2 полями (user_id, message_id) и при прочтении сообщения пользователям добавлять запись в эту таблицу, и, следовательно, делать выборку из этой таблицы и если в ней нет соответствующей пары, значит пользователь сообщение не прочитал

Но может быть есть более простой и правильный способ реализации?

Comment: *Есть идея создать промежуточную таблицу с 2 полями (user_id, message_id)* Это и есть правильный способ. Только дополнительно надо ввести понятие срока актуальности для сообщения, и по истечении оного удалять все записи из таблицы - иначе она будет неприлично пухнуть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в таблицу Пользователи добавить поле дата_просмотра_сообщений. Если эта дата меньше даты последнего сообщения, значит есть непрочитанные сообщения.